# Google Analytics PDF Export - Error has occurred

Tags: google-analytics

I'm attempting to export five or six reports from free Google Analytics spanning only about 9 months or so. I have no difficulties getting the report to show up within Google Analytics, but when I attempt to export it to a PDF, I repeatedly get the following error:

```
An Error Has Occurred

We're sorry. The service is temporarily unavailable. Please try again in a few minutes.
```

I've been attempting to do this export several times over the past week, and a couple of months ago when I exported a similar report, I didn't have an issue with it. Anyone know of any workarounds until this gets fixed?

Comment: I've got the same issue for the last few weeks. Really annoying and don't know how to solve it. Excel export does work.

Comment: Please click on the link below to upvote this issue rasied on Google support forms
link: https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/3970266?hl=en Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a google support question, not a programming question

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same issue.

A workaround is to send the PDF via email.

Comment: Thanks for that workaround, I didn't think of it. I was trying to extract my jan reports since last week.

Comment: Google Support Forms: "Here's 41 people complaining of same the problem in 2019" Stack Overflow: "Here's a viable workaround submitted in 2017". This is a win for the community - awesome, keep it up!